Is $A/I\otimes_C B/J$ always isomorphic to $A\otimes_C B/\langle I\otimes 1,1\otimes J\rangle$?
Let $A$ and $B$ and commutative $C$-algebras, then in what cases is the tensor product $A/I\otimes_C B/J$ isomorphic to the ring $A\otimes_CB/\langle I\otimes 1,1\otimes J\rangle$? It seems this holds when $C$ is a field, but I am failing to see what can go wrong in the case where $C$ is not a field...
In particular, we always have a map $f:A\otimes_C B\rightarrow A/I\otimes_C B/J$ induced by the projection maps $A\rightarrow A/I$ and $B\rightarrow B/J$. This clearly factors through quotient $A\otimes_CB/\langle I\otimes 1,1\otimes J\rangle$ as $f(I\otimes 1)=f(1\otimes J)=0$, so there is always a unique map $\tilde{f}:A\otimes_CB/\langle I\otimes 1,1\otimes J\rangle \rightarrow A/I\otimes_CB/J$.
Finding a map in the reverse direction seems to be trickier, but still possible. I think we can probably take $i_A:A\rightarrow A\otimes_C B$, given by $a\mapsto \otimes 1$, and then compose it with with the projection $\pi:A\otimes_C B\rightarrow A\otimes_CB/\langle I\otimes 1,J\otimes 1\rangle$ to get a map $\tilde{i}_A:A\rightarrow A\otimes_CB/\langle I\otimes 1,J\otimes 1\rangle$. Then $\tilde{i}_A(I)=0$, so we have a unique map $i_A':A/I\rightarrow A\otimes_CB/\langle I\otimes 1,1\otimes J\rangle$, and doing the same thing for $B$ gives us a unique map $i_B':B/J\rightarrow A\otimes_CB/\langle I\otimes 1,1\otimes J\rangle$, so the universal property of the tensor product gives us a unique map $g:A/I\otimes_CB/J\rightarrow A\otimes_CB/\langle I\otimes 1,1\otimes J\rangle$.
I think these are inverses of each other? Let $[a\otimes b]\in A\otimes_CB\langle I\otimes 1,1\otimes J\rangle$, then $\tilde{f}([a\otimes b])=[a]\otimes [b]\in A/I\otimes B/J$, and
$$g([a]\otimes [b])=g([a]\otimes 1)g(1\otimes [b])=i_{A}'([a])\cdot i_B'([b])=[a\otimes 1]\cdot [1\otimes b]=[a\otimes b]$$, so that composition is the identity. The other direction gives $g([a]\otimes [b])=[a\otimes b]$, and then $\tilde{f}([a\otimes b])=[a]\otimes [b]$, so it seems like it works...
I am only hesitant by the work above because I can only seem to find this result in the cases where the tensor product is of the form $C/I\otimes_C C/J$, or when $C$ is a field, so I am not completely sure if I have missed something or not.
I will note, that if I am incorrect I am particularly interested in the case of $B_\mathfrak p/\mathfrak m_\mathfrak p\otimes_BA$, where $A$ is any $B$ algebra, $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal, $B_\mathfrak p$ is the localization $(B-\mathfrak p)^{-1}B$, and $\mathfrak m_\mathfrak p$ is the unique prime ideal of $B_{\mathfrak p}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Yes, they're (naturally) isomorphic. This is a standard universal property argument: both constructions are the universal commutative $C$-algebra admitting a $C$-algebra map from both $A$ and $B$ such that the images of both $I$ and $J$ vanish, just that each construction imposes the two relevant conditions in the two different possible orders. This is more generally a "colimits commute with colimits" type result.
